# Meaning of "make excuses"

Tags: idioms

Please help me understand an item in a self-report questionnaire: "When I am blamed for something, I make excuses."

My intuitive understanding of it is something like this: when I am blamed for something, I tend to come up with excuses like "but I had had a bad day" or "But they verbally attacked me first" or "but I was thinking about something else".

Anther person understood it to mean something like: when I am blamed for something, I apologize.

How would a native speaker understand it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I concur with you, and interpret "*I make excuses*" the same as you - that I come up with reasons (which might not be very justifiable) to justify what it is I'm being blamed for.

EOLD gives the following definitions for [**excuse**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/excuse):

> 1 Seek to lessen the blame attaching to (a fault or offence); try to
>   justify.
>
> 1.1 Forgive (someone) for a fault or offence.
>
> 1.2 Overlook or make allowances for.
>
> 1.3 (of a fact) serve to mitigate (a person or act).
>
> *(another meaning of excuse is to release (someone) from a duty or
>   requirement, which I've not shown here)*

Based on the above definitions, it appears that the person you're referring to has probably misunderstood the meaning given under 1.1 "Forgive (someone) for a fault or offence".

However, the usage of excuse in such a context is different. Quoting EOLD's example for 1.1: "*‘you must excuse my brother’*".

To conclude, your interpretation of "excuse" is correct, and matches the definition specified as 1.